# gnome 3: how to remove delay on window events

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell

Some window events in gnome 3 seem to have an associated delay. I have a fast PC so it's probably a feature of gnome 3:

- after clicking the X in the top-right of a window, there is a delay of about 0.5s before the window closes
- moving a maximized window between screens, there is a delay of about 0.5s before it moves. (You can even do the whole drag and release the mouse button while the window is still on the old screen.)
- maximixing a window from the window list, there is a 0.5s delay while the "maximize animation" is played

These delays get really annoying after a while. Is there any way to disable them? Thanks!

Comment: It's certainly not a 'feature'. Might be just gnome-shell acting up. Which version? Does it go away after restarting the shell via Alt+F2 "r"?

Comment: Yes. Restating fixed it. Thanks. I wonder what the problem was...

Comment: No idea, it does tend to become laggy after several days of continued use. Should be better in GNOME 3.16.

Comment: I've found how to remove one of them: [Alt-Tab Switcher Popup Delay Removal](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1317) or [Remove Alt+Tab Delay](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1403).